# Elastic layouts, examples in the real world

Tags: html, responsive-design, elasticlayout

I have been looking for some examples of the use of elastic layouts (layouts based on using em's for widths) in the real world and I am struggling to find any examples of it being used. Would be really grateful if anyone is aware of any

Comment: Questions asking us for examples are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO OSɟOǝɔuᴉɹԀɥsǝɹℲ... See what I did there?

Comment: @DaveNewton Please hold while I rotate my monitor.

Comment: No no, your *life* got flip turned upside down, not your *monitor*.

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit off topic, basically I am writing a piece on responsive development and I talk about elastic layouts briefly and I would have liked to include some examples, this post was just for research purposes really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the "Goldilocks Approach". It uses ems for elastic layout.

http://goldilocksapproach.com/